# How do I setup resources in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 4 pipelines in Azure DevOps for 2 separate codebases (Alpha and Omega) within the same monorepo.

|  | Alpha | Omega |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **CI** | Alpha CI | Omega CI |
| **Full** | Alpha Full Build | Omega Full Build |

The codebase for Alpha rarely changes and so doesn't need to be built often. The codebase for Omega changes frequently, and the Omega build is dependent on the Alpha build. I want to make these pipelines efficient by making use of resources to resuse the Alpha builds when the code has only changed in the Omega codebase.

The CI builds are used for **feature/*** branches.

| Changes in Alpha | Changes in Omega | Changes in Both |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Just build 'Alpha CI Build' | Reuse 'Alpha **Full** Build' from main that the feature branch is based on and build 'Omega CI Build' | Build 'Alpha CI Build' for feature branch and then build 'Omega CI Build' |

The full builds are used for **main and release/*** branches.

| Changes in Alpha | Changes in Omega | Changes in Both |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Just build 'Alpha Full Build' | Reuse latest 'Alpha Full Build' from main and build 'Omega Full Build' | Build 'Alpha Full Build' and then build 'Omega Full Build' |

I've tried to do this already and I've had some success.

|  | Changes in Alpha | Changes in Omega | Changes in Both |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **CI** | No resource required | Incorrectly using the latest build from main | Incorrectly using the latest build from main |
| **Full** | No resource required | Correctly using the latest build from main | Incorrectly using the latest build from main |

Here are the yaml files.

```yaml
# Alpha CI Build

stages:
  - template: alpha.yml
```

```yaml
# Omega CI Build

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: AlphaFullBuild-Resource
    source: Alpha Full Build
  - pipeline: AlphaCI-Resource
    source: Alpha CI

stages:
  # - template: alpha-build.yml  # This is what we do currently without resources
  - template: omega-build.yml
    parameters:
        isFullBuild: false
```

```yaml
# Alpha Full Build

stages:
  - template: alpha.yml
```

```yaml
# Omega Full Build

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: AlphaFullBuild-Resource
    source: Alpha Full Build

stages:
  # - template: alpha-build.yml  # This is what we do currently without resources
  - template: omega-build.yml
    parameters:
        isFullBuild: true
```

```yaml
# The step within 'omega-build.yml' I use to get the resource

steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  continueOnError: false
  enabled: true
  timeoutInMinutes: 3
  inputs:
    artifactName: AlphaArtifact
    buildType: specific
    specificBuildWithTriggering: true
    buildVersionToDownload: latestFromBranch
    project: AlphaOmega-Project
    ${{ if eq(parameters.isFullBuild, 'true') }}: # This is clearly wrong but I wasn't sure how to proceed from here
      definition: $(resources.pipeline.AlphaFullBuild-Resource.pipelineID)
    ${{ else }}:
      definition: $(resources.pipeline.AlphaCI-Resource.pipelineID)
```

Is it possible to use the resources in Azure DevOps in the way that I have proposed? Also how do we handle manually running the Omega Full Build Pipeline for any branch?